# Kafka: The connection was reset error in browser and INFO exited: sample-data (exit status 0; expected)

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have run the following command while making the kafka cluster up

```
sudo docker compose up kafka-cluster
```

i have successfully access the Landoop UI portal a day ago but when i shutdown the system and perform the same steps again. I am now unable to access the landoop ui from this local URL

```
http://127.0.0.1:3030
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the following logs has been generated in the terminal.

```
[sudo] password for pc-11: 
[+] Running 1/0
 ⠿ Container code-kafka-cluster-1  Created                                                                                                                                      0.0s
Attaching to code-kafka-cluster-1
code-kafka-cluster-1  | Setting advertised host to 127.0.0.1.
code-kafka-cluster-1  | Starting services.
code-kafka-cluster-1  | This is landoop’s fast-data-dev. Kafka 0.11.0.0, Confluent OSS 3.3.0.
code-kafka-cluster-1  | You may visit http://127.0.0.1:3030 in about a minute.
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,716 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/01-zookeeper.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/02-broker.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/03-schema-registry.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/04-rest-proxy.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/05-connect-distributed.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/06-caddy.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/07-smoke-tests.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/08-logs-to-kafka.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,729 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisord.d/99-supervisord-sample-data.conf" during parsing
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:34,731 INFO supervisord started with pid 7
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,735 INFO spawned: 'sample-data' with pid 91
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,753 INFO spawned: 'zookeeper' with pid 93
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,766 INFO spawned: 'caddy' with pid 94
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,770 INFO spawned: 'broker' with pid 95
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,773 INFO spawned: 'smoke-tests' with pid 97
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,776 INFO spawned: 'connect-distributed' with pid 98
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,779 INFO spawned: 'logs-to-kafka' with pid 99
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,782 INFO spawned: 'schema-registry' with pid 100
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:35,785 INFO spawned: 'rest-proxy' with pid 101
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:36,262 INFO exited: caddy (exit status 2; not expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,264 INFO success: sample-data entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,264 INFO success: zookeeper entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,266 INFO spawned: 'caddy' with pid 381
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,267 INFO success: broker entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,267 INFO success: smoke-tests entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,267 INFO success: connect-distributed entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,267 INFO success: logs-to-kafka entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,267 INFO success: schema-registry entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,268 INFO success: rest-proxy entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:37,280 INFO exited: caddy (exit status 2; not expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:39,285 INFO spawned: 'caddy' with pid 389
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:39,348 INFO exited: caddy (exit status 2; not expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:42,444 INFO spawned: 'caddy' with pid 403
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:42,450 INFO exited: caddy (exit status 2; not expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:48:42,508 INFO gave up: caddy entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:49:04,090 INFO exited: schema-registry (exit status 1; not expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:49:04,099 INFO spawned: 'schema-registry' with pid 485
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:49:05,124 INFO success: schema-registry entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:49:35,818 INFO exited: smoke-tests (exit status 0; expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:51:35,933 INFO exited: logs-to-kafka (exit status 0; expected)
code-kafka-cluster-1  | 2022-07-14 08:52:53,146 INFO exited: sample-data (exit status 0; expected)
```

Comment: `fast-data-dev` is no longer maintained. I suggest you find a new repo such as Confluent `cp-all-in-one` repo

Comment: so how would i switch between its new variant? As i am pulling the ready-made container, should i have to made some changing in Yaml file Configuration?

Comment: I am pulling this image `landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0` in my yaml file would you like to suggest anything else ? to change my yaml file image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution as `fast-data-dev` is not maintained so we can make changing in the my configuration or `mydocker_compose.yml` I have replaced the `landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0` with `landoop/fast-data-dev:latest`My final `docker-compose.yml` is as follows:

```
version: '2'

services:
  # this is our kafka cluster.
  kafka-cluster:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:latest
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1         # Change to 192.168.99.100 if using Docker Toolbox
      RUNTESTS: 0                 # Disable Running tests so the cluster starts faster
    ports:
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker

  # we will use elasticsearch as one of our sinks.
  # This configuration allows you to start elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: itzg/elasticsearch:2.4.3
    environment:
      PLUGINS: appbaseio/dejavu
      OPTS: -Dindex.number_of_shards=1 -Dindex.number_of_replicas=0
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"

  # we will use postgres as one of our sinks.
  # This configuration allows you to start postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.5-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres     # define credentials
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres # define credentials
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres       # define database
    ports:
      - 5432:5432                 # Postgres port
```

And after just updating the image with the latest and i was able to get the landoop ui on `127.0.0.1:3030`

I am also able to get the access the landoop ui even shutting down the cluster and accessing it again.

Comment: Still, latest tag doesn't change anything. It isn't maintained. See this for recommendation of individual containers and latest versions of Confluent components https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.1.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml You can add the Landoop UI components as separate containers, or just use Confluent Control Center as long as you have one broker

Comment: Yes, but can you anticipate than why i was able to access the landoop UI again even i have shut down the kafka clusetr? My issue was just the same to access it later, which now i am able to access when i used the `latest`, and thank you sending me confluent blog post on github.

Comment: The Landoop UI doesn't need a running broker to display HTML response, so I don't understand the question